# OpenMP on a 2-socket system

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, openmp

I do some scientific computations in C++, and try to utilize OpenMP for the parallelisation of some of the loops.
This worked well so far, e.g. on a Intel i7-4770 with 8 threads.

## Setup

We have a small workstation which consists of two Intel CPUs (E5-2680v2) on one mainboard.
The code works as long as it runs on 1 CPU with as many threads as I like. But as soon as I employ the second CPU, I observe incorrect results from time to time (around every 50th-100th time I run the code).
This happens even when I use only 2 threads and assign them to the two different CPUs.
As we have 5 of these workstations (all are identical), I ran the code on each one of them, and all show this problem.

The workstation runs on OpenSuse 13.1, kernel 3.11.10-7.
The problem exists with g++ 4.8.1 and 4.9.0, and with Intel's icc 13.1.3.192 (albeit the problem doesn't occur that often with icc, but it is still there).

## The symptom

The symptom can be described as follows:

- I have a large array of std::complex: `std::complex<double>* mFourierValues;`
- In the loop, I access and set each element. Each iteration accesses a different element, so I do not have concurrent accesses (I checked this): `mFourierValues[idx] = newValue;`
- If I compare the set array-value to the input-value afterwards, roughly `mFourierValues[idx] == newValue`, this check fails from time to time (although not every time the results end up being incorrect).

So the symptom looks like I access elements concurrently without any synchronizations. However, when I store the indices in a `std::vector` (with a proper `#pragma omp critical`),
all indicies are unique and in the correct range.

## Questions

After several days of debugging, my suspicion grows that something else is going on, and that my code is correct.
To me it looks like something weird is happening when the CPUs synchronize the caches with the main-memory.

Therefore, my questions are:

- Can OpenMP even be used for such a system? (I haven't found a source which says no.)
- Are there known bugs for such a situation (I haven't found any in the bug-trackers)?
- Where is the problem probably located in your opinion?

  - My code (which seems to run fine on 1 CPU with multiple cores!),
  - the compilers (gcc, icc both!),
  - the OS,
  - the hardware (defect on all 5 workstations?)

## Code

[Edit: Old code removed, see below]

## Edit with minimal example

OK, I was finally able to produce a shorter (and self-consistent) code example.

### About the code

- Reserve some memory space. For an array on the stack, this would be accessed like: `complex<double> mAllElements[tensorIdx][kappa1][kappa2][kappa3]`. I.e. I have 3 rank-3-tensors (`tensorIdx`). Each tensor represents a 3-dimensional array, indexed by `kappa1`, `kappa2` and `kappa3`.
- I have 4 nested loops (over all 4 indices), whereas the `kappa1` loop is the one that gets parallized (and is the outermost one). They are located in `DoComputation()`.
- In `main()`, I call `DoComputation()` once to get some reference values, and then I call it several times and compare the results. They should match exactly, but sometimes they don't.

Unfortunately, the code is still around 190 lines long. I tried to simplify it further (only 1 tensor of rank 1, etc.), but then I was never able to reproduce the problem. I guess it appears because the memory-accesses are non-aligned (the loop over `tensorIdx` is the innermost one) (I know, this is far from optimal.)

Furthermore, some delays were needed in appropriate places, to reproduce the bug. That is the reason for the `nops()` calls. Without them the code runs a lot faster, but so far hasn't shown the problem.

Note that I checked the critical part, `CalcElementIdx()`, again, and deem it correct (each element is accessed once). I also ran valgrind's memcheck, helgrind and drd (with proper recompiled libgomp), and all three gave no errors.

### Output

Every second to third start of the program I get one or two mismatches. Example output:

```
41      Is exactly 0
42      Is exactly 0
43      Is exactly 0
44      Is exactly 0
45      348496
46      Is exactly 0
47      Is exactly 0
48      Is exactly 0
49      Is exactly 0
```

This is true for gcc and icc.

### My question

My question is: Does the code below look correct to you? (Apart from obvious design flaws.)
(If it is too long, I will try to reduce it further, but as described above I failed so far.)

### The code

The code was compiled with

```
g++ main.cc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -fopenmp
```

or

```
icc main.cc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -openmp
```

Both version show the described problem when run on 2 CPUs with a total of 40 threads. I couldn't observe the bug on 1 CPU (and as many threads as I like).

```
// File: main.cc
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;


// If defined: We add some nops in certain places, to get the timing right.
// Without them, I haven't observed the bug.
#define ENABLE_NOPS

// The size of each of the 3 tensors is: GRID_SIZE x GRID_SIZE x GRID_SIZE
static const int GRID_SIZE = 60;

//=============================================
// Produces several nops. Used to get correct "timings".

//----
template<int N> __attribute__((always_inline)) inline void nop()
{
    nop<N-1>();
    asm("nop;");
}

//----
template<> inline void nop<0>() { }

//----
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void nops()
{
    nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>(); nop<500>();
}




//=============================================
/*
Memory layout: We have 3 rank-3-tensors, i.e. 3 arrays of dimension 3.
The layout looks like this: complex<double> allElements[tensorIdx][kappa1][kappa2][kappa3];
The kappas represent the indices into a certain tensor, and are all in the interval [0; GRID_SIZE-1].
*/
class MemoryManagerFFTW
{
public:
  //---------- Constructor ----------
  MemoryManagerFFTW()
  {
    mAllElements = new complex<double>[GetTotalNumElements()];
  }

  //---------- Destructor ----------
  ~MemoryManagerFFTW() 
  { 
    delete[] mAllElements; 
  }

  //---------- SetElement ----------
  void SetElement(int tensorIdx, int kappa1, int kappa2, int kappa3, const complex<double>& newVal)
  {
    // Out-of-bounds error checks are done in this function.
    const size_t idx = CalcElementIdx(tensorIdx, kappa1, kappa2, kappa3);

    // These nops here are important to reproduce the bug.
#if defined(ENABLE_NOPS)
    nops();
    nops();
#endif

    // A flush makes the bug appear more often.
    // #pragma omp flush
    mAllElements[idx] = newVal;

    // This was never false, although the same check is false in DoComputation() from time to time.
    assert(newVal == mAllElements[idx]);
  }

  //---------- GetElement ----------
  const complex<double>& GetElement(int tensorIdx, int kappa1, int kappa2, int kappa3)const
  {  
    const size_t idx = CalcElementIdx(tensorIdx, kappa1, kappa2, kappa3);
    return mAllElements[idx];
  }


  //---------- CalcElementIdx ----------
  size_t CalcElementIdx(int tensorIdx, int kappa1, int kappa2, int kappa3)const
  {
    // We have 3 tensors (index by "tensorIdx"). Each tensor is of rank 3. In memory, they are placed behind each other.
    // tensorStartIdx is the index of the first element in the tensor.
    const size_t tensorStartIdx = GetNumElementsPerTensor() * tensorIdx;

    // Index of the element relative to the beginning of the tensor. A tensor is a 3dim. array of size GRID_SIZE x GRID_SIZE x GRID_SIZE
    const size_t idxInTensor = kappa3 + GRID_SIZE * (kappa2 + GRID_SIZE * kappa1);

    const size_t finalIdx = tensorStartIdx + idxInTensor;
    assert(finalIdx < GetTotalNumElements());

    return finalIdx;
  }


  //---------- GetNumElementsPerTensor & GetTotalNumElements ----------
  size_t GetNumElementsPerTensor()const { return GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE; }
  size_t GetTotalNumElements()const { return NUM_TENSORS * GetNumElementsPerTensor(); }



public:
  static const int NUM_TENSORS = 3; // The number of tensors.
  complex<double>* mAllElements; // All tensors. An array [tensorIdx][kappa1][kappa2][kappa3]
};




//=============================================
void DoComputation(MemoryManagerFFTW& mSingleLayerManager)
{
  // Parallize outer loop.
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int kappa1 = 0; kappa1 < GRID_SIZE; ++kappa1)
  {
    for (int kappa2 = 0; kappa2 < GRID_SIZE; ++kappa2)
    {
      for (int kappa3 = 0; kappa3 < GRID_SIZE; ++kappa3)
      {    
#ifdef ENABLE_NOPS
        nop<50>();
#endif
        const double k2 = kappa1*kappa1 + kappa2*kappa2 + kappa3*kappa3;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
          // Compute and set new result.
          const complex<double> curElement = mSingleLayerManager.GetElement(j, kappa1, kappa2, kappa3);
          const complex<double> newElement = exp(-k2) * k2 * curElement;

          mSingleLayerManager.SetElement(j, kappa1, kappa2, kappa3, newElement);

          // Check if the results has been set correctly. This is sometimes false, but _not_ always when the result is incorrect.
          const complex<double> test = mSingleLayerManager.GetElement(j, kappa1, kappa2, kappa3);
          if (test != newElement)
            printf("Failure: (%g, %g) != (%g, %g)\n", test.real(), test.imag(), newElement.real(), newElement.imag());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



//=============================================
int main()
{
  cout << "Max num. threads: " << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;

  // Call DoComputation() once to get a reference-array.
  MemoryManagerFFTW reference;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < reference.GetTotalNumElements(); ++i)
    reference.mAllElements[i] = complex<double>((double)i, (double)i+0.5);
  DoComputation(reference);

  // Call DoComputation() several times, and each time compare the result to the reference.
  const size_t NUM = 1000;
  for (size_t curTry = 0; curTry < NUM; ++curTry)
  {
    MemoryManagerFFTW mSingleLayerManager;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mSingleLayerManager.GetTotalNumElements(); ++i)
      mSingleLayerManager.mAllElements[i] = complex<double>((double)i, (double)i+0.5);
    DoComputation(mSingleLayerManager);

    // Get the max. difference. This *should* be 0, but isn't from time to time.
    double maxDiff = -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mSingleLayerManager.GetTotalNumElements(); ++i)
    {
      const complex<double> curDiff = mSingleLayerManager.mAllElements[i] - reference.mAllElements[i];
      maxDiff = max(maxDiff, max(curDiff.real(), curDiff.imag()));
    }

    if (maxDiff != 0)
      cout << curTry << "\t" << maxDiff << endl;
    else
      cout << curTry << "\t" << "Is exactly 0" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

## Edit

As can be seen from the comments and Zboson's answer below, there was a bug in kernel 3.11.10-7. After an update to 3.15.0-1, my problem is gone, and the code works as it should.

Comment: What you have is called a NUMA system and OpenMP can be used for a NUMA system. I don't know why you're having problems yet.  Almost sounds like you should used `#pragma omp flush` but nobody has every shown me a good example of when `#pragam omp flush` should be used.  BTW, you could pull the special case kappa1,2,3,=0 out of the loop but I don't think it will help solve your problem.

Comment: I agree with @Zboson - we can't answer your question without a reproducer, but OpenMP is routinely used across sockets, and it would be a catastrophic and frequently encountered bug in a compiler's OpenMP implementation (or the moboard memory management hardware) to get that wrong.  So even though you've looked carefully, my suspicion is still that there's a subtle memory issue in your code.  Keep trying to get a reproducer, and/or look carefully at the documents describing the OpenMP memory model.

Comment: @Zboson, what makes you think that this is a NUMA system?  Multiple sockets doesn't necessarily mean that the system is NUMA.

Comment: @ChrisO, well I don't know.  I just started working with a four socket NUMA system.  I guess I don't have enough experience to know any better.  Can you give me an example of a multisocket system which is not a shared memory system?

Comment: First sentence from wiki on OpenMP "OpenMP (Open Multi-Processing) is an API that supports multi-platform shared memory multiprocessing programming"...if NUMA is not shared memory then OpenMP would not work with it...

Comment: @Zboson A `#pragma omp flush` before I set an array element has the effect that the bug appears more often. @Jonathan @Chris I updated my post with a minimal example. Furthermore, the workstation has `numastat` available, so I guess it is a NUMA system.

Comment: @Gugi, like I said, nobody has every shown me a good example as to when `#pragma omp flush` should be used :-)

Comment: @gugi, why do you need to use `nop` to get the timing right? And I don't remember you saying that the bug only happens when you use `nop`.  That's interesting.  Are you sure you need `nop`?

Comment: @Zboson The bug is not tied to `nop`. Of course I haven't any `nops` in my real-world code. However, I do have additional statements in it (like additional terms in the computation, etc.), which slow things down. And so far I observed the bug only when the code is "running slow enough". For the minimal example I replaced most of these additional statements with `nops` for the sake of simplicity. If I replace the `nops` in `SetElement()` with a `#pragma omp atomic \ ++myCounter;`, the code runs "slow enough" again (but please note that the bug is independent of any `atomic`). I know, absurd...

Comment: @ChrisO, Intel CPUs since Nehalem have built-in memory controller and therefore single-board multi-socket systems **are** NUMA systems.

Comment: @Zboson, I guess what Chris O means is that a multi-socket system is a shared memory system but not necessarily a NUMA one. Older multi-socket Intel systems with CPUs before Nehalem share a single memory controller in the North bridge and suchs systems are UMA and not NUMA.

Comment: Instead of banging your head against the wall, I would recommend that you run your code with a tool like Intel's Inspector XE (formerly known as Intel Thread Checker) and have it inspect (pardon the pun) the program's behaviour for data races. The [Helgrind tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) from the Valgrind package could also be used but it doesn't fully understand the OpenMP runtimes and might give some false positives.

Comment: What happens if you change complex to use `__attribute__((__aligned__(64)))`?  That should force each element onto its own cache line.  If the problem is cache line writes overwriting each other, the problem should disappear.  If the problem is something with indexing the array, it won't.  Check sizeof() to make sure you have adjusted the right thing in complex.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, I already tried valgrind's memcheck, helgrind and drd (both the full code, and the minimal example). For helgrind and drd I recompiled gcc to get a compatible libgomp (as described in the manual). None of the 3 tools found any errors. However, I never observed the bug while running the tools. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Intel's Inspector at the university; I'll try it later at home with the free version.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thank you for the tip. When I add the attribute (align 64), the bug does _not_ occur anymore (or at least is hidden now). sizeof(complex<double>) is 64. Interestingly the allocated memory is _not_ aligned to 64 bytes, but to 16 bytes. But still the bug seems to be gone. So, if it is a problem with the cache-lines: Where is the problem located (most likely)? OS, hardware, code?

Comment: Memory allocated with `malloc()` or `new ` is not aligned because of the linked list header. You should use `posix_memalign()` to allocate an aligned block of memory and then the placement `new` operator to initialise it. Anyway, could you check what array indices produce the non-zero differences? I'm running your code on an 8-socket Xeon X7550 system with kernel 2.6.32 and the bug does not occur neither with GCC 4.8.2 nor with any recent version of ICC.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, I know that memory allocated via `new` can be unaligned. Regarding the indices: The problem is that I need a huge array-size (in the example: 648000 elements) (I failed to reproduce the problem for much smaller sizes). But I did write out the accessed elements, observed the bug, took the written indices, and executed the operations (the 4 loops) in exactly this order (serially). Result: It worked, no errors.

Comment: @HristoIliev Also thank you very much for trying out the code! I just tried another system, running on two AMD Opteron 6348 (CentOS 6.4, kernel 2.6.32, gcc 4.4.7), and so far I haven't observed the bug.

Comment: My idea was that you can write down the indices and convert them back to coordinates and check if the affected elements lie somewhere on the border between memory regions worked on by different threads, possibly in the same cache line. Though, if there is a problem with the cache coherence of your system(s), it would manifest itself in many other catastrophic ways...

Comment: While I'm reluctant to call this a hw problem (like @Hristo says, it seems like it would affect lots of things), I'm not prepared to dismiss the idea either.  Sometimes problems only appear under very specific circumstances and maybe you just got 'lucky'.  Since I believe complex<double> has a constructor that sets members to zero, if there were a cache line problem, I'd expect that the 'wrong' value would be zero.  What happens if you print the actual real/imag values instead of the diff?  If they *aren't* zero, do the match some other element?

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for the suggestion. I just did the following: In `SetElement()`, I store the core-number of the calling thread (via `sched_getcpu()`) in a `std::vector` (wrapped in `omp critical`). Then, in `main()`, I find the elements that do not match the reference. Observation: Lets say a mismatching element has index `518584`, and this element was set by core `1`. Then at least elements `518574-518594` were also set by core `1` (i.e +-10 elements). So: Incorrect elements and their neighbours were never touched by another core! It's getting more and more absurd...

Comment: @Gugi, I tested your code sample on a four socket system, 4x Xeon E7- 4850, with 80 hardware threads (20 per processor) 1000 iterations and had no errors.

Comment: @Gugi, maybe there is a bug in kernel 3.11.10-7?  You could try updating the Linux Kernel or installing Linux with a different Kernel on a USB then boot from USB and test your code.

Comment: This sounds very much like bug with handling the invalidation of the TLB cache. Searching for "Linux 3.11 TLB cache" I found [this bug in 3.11](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2014-January/037185.html). I would strongly recommend that you do what **Z boson** suggests and try with a different kernel version.

Comment: @Zboson Thank you very much for testing! Have you tried running it multiple times? (Like starting it 3-4 times in a row?) Because sometimes the problem doesn't show itself immediately.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you for searching! (Of course, I also searched for bugs in the kernel, but without a proper keyword (TLB cache) it is hard...). I will get in touch with our server-administrator, and ask him for possibilities (the "workstations" are actually 5 nodes which form a small cluster). I will let you know the results.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Actually, before doing the computations, I set the elements to their indicies (see `main()`). Then, in the actual computations, the stored elements are used, and the new values are set. In this last step the problem appears. Also, so far I haven't found any pattern in the errorneous elements that matches any other element. Indeed, sometimes only 1 single `complex<double>` is incorrect.

Comment: @Gugi, no, I just ran it once with the default of 1000 iterations.  It finished quickly on that system.

Comment: @Gugi, I ran your code three times in a row with no errors on the same NUMA system I used before which has Linux Kernel 2.6.X.

Comment: @Zboson Many thanks again! So, taking all together (your run, Hristo's run, and my run on the Opteron system), it seems, that: 1) The bug only occurs on our workstation, or 2) That the required timings are in a pretty narrow window. Well, lets see what a kernel-update will do...

Comment: Seems you have several others who have tested it already, but I also can't reproduce your issue on any of our numa systems, ranging from 8 to 48 cores and 2-4 sockets.  Given the evidence here, it may well be that you are actually seeing memory errors, a run with good old memtest86 or similar may be in order.  I especially recommend this if your system does not have ECC RAM.

Comment: @njustn Thank you for testing the code! Actually, we have 5 identical workstations (they do have ECC RAM), and all 5 show the same behaviour. So the hardware itself should be working correctly. Anyway, I hope tomorrow I will be able to try out the newest kernel (today is a holiday at my location).

Comment: @Zboson OK, the program did 3037000 iterations so far without any problems on kernel 3.15.0-1! So I really stumbled upon a kernel-bug. Thank you all **VERY** **MUCH** for your help, and for trying out my code!! So, I guess, as Zboson was the first to suggest a kernel-update, which turned out to be the solution, I should accept his answer to give him the deserved reputation :) Zboson, could you post an answer so that I can accept it? (Hristolliev, I would like to accept your answer, too, because you found the TLB-Bug, which might have been the cause, but I guess I can't accept 2 answers?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was due to a bug in Linux Kernel kernel 3.11.10-7. [The bug may be due to how the kernel handles invalidating the TLB cache](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2014-January/037185.html) as pointed out by Hristo Iliev.  I guessed that the kernel might be the problem because I read that there would be some improvements in [Linux Kernel 3.15 for NUMA systems](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/features/linux-kernel-3-15-development-the-kernel-column) so I figured that the kernel version is important for NUMA systems.

When the OP updated the Linux kernel of his NUMA system to 3.15.0-1 the problem went away.