# OpenMp doesn't utilize all CPUs(dual socket, windows and Microsoft visual studio)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, multiprocessing, openmp

I have a dual socket system with 22 real cores per CPU or 44 hyperthreads per CPU. I can get openMP to completely utilize the first CPU(22 cores/44 hyper) but I cannot get it to utilize the second CPU.

I am using CPUID HWMonitor to check my core usage. The second CPU is always at or near 0 % on all cores.

Using:

```
int nProcessors = omp_get_max_threads();
```

gets me nProcessors = 44, but I think it's just using the 44 hyperthreads of 1 CPU instead of 44 real cores(should be 88 hyperthreads)

After looking around a lot, I'm not sure how to utilize the other CPU.

My CPU is running fine as I can run other parallel processing programs that utilize all of them.

I'm compiling this in 64 bit but I don't think that matters. Also, I'm using Visual studio 2017 Professional version 15.2. Open MP 2.0(only one vs supports). Running on a windows 10 Pro, 64 bit, with 2 Intel Xeon E5-2699v4 @ 2.2Ghz processors.

Comment: It might help to mention what operating system you are using and which compiler and OpenMP versions/implementations you are using.

Comment: You can enforce the number of thread using `omp_set_num_threads` and `omp_set_dynamic(false)` to disable dynamic teams. I'm not sure how that behaves on a 2-socket setup though. Maybe [this read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219263/openmp-on-a-2-socket-system) might give a bit of answer?

Comment: You can set thread count and it behaves fine, how threads are allocated then depends on the OS. It is possible the OS tries to keep them all on the same CPU to ensure faster memory access, I don't really know how Windows behaves on multi-socket machines (or which versions even support it - I assume not all do).

Comment: @AlexG: I set the num_threads to 44 and 88(just in case it's thinking hyperthreading is a thread?) with omp_set_dynamic to false, and still it doesn't utilize the other CPU. The post you mentioned was due to a linux kernel bug, which ties in to what Qubit may be mentioning about how Windows handles things. That's why I'm kind of at a loss as to what else I can do to help solve the problem. Should I be getting 44 threads back right now as max threads? Or should it be 88? I'm not certain of that.

Comment: @Marvg you might want to read [this](https://openmpcon.org/wp-content/uploads/2018_Tutorial3_Martorell_Teruel_Klemm.pdf), and [this](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-affinity.html). Not sure in which version OMP_PLACES came out (I think OpenMP 4.0), but it seems relevant to your case.

Comment: @AlexG : After reading what you posted, seems that (a) Visual Studio supports an older version of openmp(2.0), more importantly, (b) Windows doesn't allow a process to use more than one processor group by default, which is limited to 64 logical cores(I have 88 logical). Windows splits mine into two processor groups, both with 44 logical, which is why I notice sometimes one CPU gets the load vs the other. I can only use the other CPU if I explicitly create the threads instead of openmp doing so. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/processor-groups)

Comment: @AlexG a little success! on a omp parallel block I set each thread's processor group affinity using SetThreadGroupAffinity. Problem is that openMP won't give me more than 64 threads, so I set the group affinity of half of it to group 0 and the other half to group 1, which is the only way to force windows into using 2 cpus in a process. So now I have 32 hyperthreads running on each CPU for a total of 64 out of the 88 hyperthreads I have, at least an improvement!

Comment: At the end of the day, seems like a Microsoft visual studio issue, limiting its openMP implementation to 64 threads maximum: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/772c339d-27d5-4992-bcff-8a30f5077edf/couldnt-create-more-than-64-openmp-threads-in-a-test-application?forum=parallelcppnative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering my own question with thanks to @AlexG for providing some insight. Please see comments section of question.

This is a Microsoft Visual Studio and Windows problem.

First read [Processor Groups for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/processor-groups).

Basically, if you have under 64 logical cores, this would not be a problem. Once you get past that, however, you will now have two process groups for each socket(or other organization Windows so chooses). In my case, each process group had 44 hyperthreads and represented one physical CPU socket and I had exactly two process groups. Every process(program) by default, is only given access to one process group, hence I initially could only utilize 44 threads on one core. However, if you manually create threads and use SetThreadGroupAffinity to set the thread's processor group to one that is different from your program's initially assigned group, then your program now becomes a multi processor group. This seems like a round-about way to enable multi-processors but yes this is how to do it. A call to GetProcessGroupAffinity will show that the number of groups becomes greater than 1 once you start setting each thread's individual process group.

I was able to create an open MP block like so, and go through and assign process groups:

...

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads( 88 )
{
    HANDLE thread = GetCurrentThread();

    if (omp_get_thread_num() > 32)
    {
        // Reserved has to be zero'd out after each use if reusing structure...
        GroupAffinity1.Reserved[0] = 0;
        GroupAffinity1.Reserved[1] = 0;
        GroupAffinity1.Reserved[2] = 0;
        GroupAffinity1.Group = 0;
        GroupAffinity1.Mask = 1 << (omp_get_thread_num()%32);
        if (SetThreadGroupAffinity(thread, &GroupAffinity1, &previousAffinity))
        {
            sprintf(buf, "Thread set to group 0: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            OutputDebugString(buf);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Reserved has to be zero'd out after each use if reusing structure...
        GroupAffinity2.Reserved[0] = 0;
        GroupAffinity2.Reserved[1] = 0;
        GroupAffinity2.Reserved[2] = 0;
        GroupAffinity2.Group = 1;
        GroupAffinity2.Mask = 1 << (omp_get_thread_num() % 32);
        if (SetThreadGroupAffinity(thread, &GroupAffinity2, &previousAffinity))
        {
            sprintf(buf, "Thread set to group 1: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            OutputDebugString(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

So with the above code, I was able to force 64 threads to run, 32 threads each per socket. Now I couldn't get over 64 threads even though I tried forcing omp_set_num_threads to 88. The reason seems to be linked to Visual Studio's implementation of OpenMP not allowing more than 64 OpenMP threads. Here's a link on that for more [information](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/772c339d-27d5-4992-bcff-8a30f5077edf/couldnt-create-more-than-64-openmp)

Thanks all for helping glean some more tidbits that helped in the eventual answer!

Comment: I'm glad you could find something. If you truly need performance, you might want to do some testing without hyperthreading too. In the best scenarios, it will give a 15% performance improvement, but if you are crunching numbers, chances are it might slow you down a bit.