# OpenMP not using all NUMA nodes

Tags: c++, openmp, numa

I'm trying to run some simple omp parallel for loops on a Intel Xeon CPU E5-4669 v3 - system with four NUMA nodes. However, for some reason, the code always utilizes all threads, but on only one of the four NUMA nodes (random one). On a single-node system, everything works as expected. My code is really simple, just a plain openmp parallel for loop, like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int i = 0; i < NP; i++)
{
// ... some code
}
```

Since the code runs on one node only but has access to all the nodes clearly (when I start it multiple times, it randomly starts on any of the nodes), I assume there is a simple fix, however, my research did not grant me any knowledge on how to fix this, all the information I found was about how to control the affinity and optimize performance, which is not yet my problem. Anyone had this problem before? I also tried setting KMP_AFFINITY environment variable to "spread", but that did not fix this problem.

OpenMP version 2.0 (Visual Studio 2017 Open MP support /openmp)

How I observed the utilization of one NUMA node only:
[image]

Comment: Please try to be more specific with your question. At the **very least** we need to know your OpenMP implementation, and specifically how you observed what you describe. Also, please add an actual [mcve].

Comment: @Zulan Thank you, added openmp information to my question. Since the problem occurs with all parallel for loops I tried, containing different code, I assume the code inside the loop is not relevant.

Comment: Even if you theorically have 18 (36) cores availables, OMP might not use all of them at the same time. have you tried looking `omp_get_num_threads()` to confirm how many are in use within your loop

Comment: you have 28 100%'s what does NP equal?

Comment: 4 sockets hmm. I've already answered/give thoughts to a question that had the similar problem. see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766303/openmp-doesnt-utilize-all-cpusdual-socket-windows-and-microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: @AlexG omp_get_num_threads() returns 36, but there's 72 cores and 144 threads, and the CPU is practically only 25% loaded for some reason.

Comment: @GradyPlayer NP was set to 144, for example, in the picture

Comment: @Zdeny yeah, I didn't expect you had more than one socket. Have a look at the link I wrote in my last comment, it will most likely answer your question. It's about the way Windows dispatch thread jobs across multiple sockets that's problematic.

Comment: Welcome to [processor groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups), windows won't let any one process cross onto multiple processor groups. This means any one process is restricted to a single socket in effect. It looks like you can override that behavior but have to be explicit in doing so.